# How SSIS get foreign key from the table?

Tags: ssis

I'm having a sql task which insert a single row record into table A each time.

Following by a data flow task which read all of the records from a csv file and save it into table B.

My question - How do I get the primary key that inserted into table A and insert it into table B ?

*Can It be done by insert the records from csv and also the primary key from table A at the same time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can select from table A last inserted record (PrimaryKey). You can use in dataflow `lookup` element and in `lookup` element write query which gonna select your wanted PrimaryKey.

Comment: I had done a lookup and able to preview the latest primary key, but after that how to store it into database ?

Comment: `Following by a data flow task which read all of the records from a csv file and save it into table B.` so how you save csv info in table B, just add taken PrimaryKey column in OLEDB destination and map... https://www.simple-talk.com/iwritefor/articlefiles/1265-Bob5.jpg